# C# equivalent of hasSameSizeAs()

Tags: c#

To check that two Iterable have same size, I can write with Java's [assertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/IterableAssertionsExamples.java)

```java
assertThat(elvesRings).hasSameSizeAs(trilogy);
```

What would be the closest equivalent in C#?

So far I only have

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(elvesRings.Count, trilogy.Count);
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual(elvesRings.Count(), trilogy.Count(), "count of elvesRings and trilogy does not match");` *Note the brackets for `Count` - c#'s equivalent to `Iterable` is `IEnumerable`, and you need to have LINQ imported with `using` so that the extension method `Count(this IEnumerable<T>)` is found*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the FluentAssertions you can use:

```
elvesRings.Should().HaveSameCount(trilogy);
```

Link for library:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions

Comment: This assumes that OP is using that library...which is unlikely.  You should at least include a link to the library if you're going to reference something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just call count on each `IEnumerable<T>` (similar to Java's `Iterable` interface):

```
Assert.AreEqual(elvesRings.Count(), trilogy.Count());
```

Notice that `Count` is called as a method and not a property.  This is because when using `IEnumerable<T>` count is an extension method, and when called with no parameters it simply counts everything within the underlying collection, even if that collection does not have a Count property.

This will work for both MS-TEST and NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially easy to roll your own extension method to do exactly this, something along the lines of:

```
public static bool hasSameSizeAs(this IEnumerable first, IEnumerable second)
{
   return first.Count() == second.Count();
}
```

Disclaimer: Error checking, potential multiple iterations of the IEnumerable, etc.

Comment: This is a nice & simple extension method, but does not actually work as a test method.  OP would then have to call `Assert.IsTrue(first.hasSameSizeAs(second));` (or whatever their testing framework uses for asserting a truth)